# no instance of overload function "get" matches the arguent list

Tags: c++

so i have been stuck with this for hours and might be too big of a dummy to find a solution myself so...

i am getting an error: "no instance of overload function "get" matches the arguent list","argument types are: (char)"

the code im trying to run is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool checkIfLowercase(string word) {

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (!islower(word[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int simpleScore(string word) {
    int wordScore=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        string letter(1, word[i]);

        if (letter == "a")
            wordScore = wordScore + 1;
        if (letter == "e")
            wordScore = wordScore + 1;
        if (letter == "i")
        //continues for other letters 

        else {
            wordScore = wordScore + 0;
        }

    }
    return wordScore;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fileWithEverything("test.txt");

    string wordFromFile;
    int amountOfWords=0;
    int x;
    vector<tuple<string, int>> vectorWithTuples;

    while (getline(fileWithEverything, wordFromFile)) {
        if (checkIfLowercase(wordFromFile) == true) {
            //cout << wordFromFile << endl;

            amountOfWords++;

            x = simpleScore(wordFromFile);

            //cout << x << endl;
            vectorWithTuples.push_back(make_tuple(wordFromFile, x));        
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wordFromFile.length(); i++) {
        cout << get<0>(wordFromFile[i]) << " ";
        cout << get<1>(wordFromFile[i]) << endl;
    }
    cout << "Amount of words is: "<<amountOfWords << endl;
}
```

how do i get rid of the error???

i have recentrly started coding so please dont be too harsh on me in the comments but do point out my mistakes :D

Answer (score 2):

`wordFromFile` is a `string`. `std::get` works on tuples.

> how do i get rid of the error???

Did you mean `get<0>(vectorWithTuples[i])` instead?

Comment: i about to cry to sleep.